# How to document with Swagger a Spring MVC request param of type List<CustomObject>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger

Spring Boot 2.1.8, Spring Web 5.1.9, Springfox Swagger 2.8.0, Swagger Annotations/Models 1.5.14

My `RestController` method signature looks like this:

```
    @ApiOperation("List statuses")
    @GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ListResult<Status> listStatuses(
            @ApiParam("Filter given IDs")
            @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false, defaultValue = "") List<String> ids,
            @ApiParam(value = "Sort by property value", allowMultiple = true, format = "propertyName:<asc|desc>", type = "array")
            @RequestParam(value = "_sort", required = false, defaultValue = "") List<Sort> sorts
    )
```

`ids` is documented as I expect - I can input multiple, separate values:

[image: ids]

However, `_sort` is always documented as a single string, no matter how I play around with different options to the `@ApiParam`. There is a custom Spring `Converter<String, Sort>` bean registered.

[image: sort]

How can I force Swagger to handle the `_sort` parameter as a list of strings where each item must have the format of `"propertyName:<asc|desc>"`?

Comment: Can you try `@ApiModelProperty(value = "Sort by property value", name="sorts", dataType = "List", format = "propertyName:<asc|desc>", example = "[value1, value2, value3]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **@ApiImplicitParam** you can force Swagger  _sort parameter as a list of strings

```
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "_sort", allowMultiple = true, dataType = "string", format = "propertyName:<asc|desc>", paramType = "query",
            value = "Sort by property value")
```

Comment: Very nice! I only couldn't make `format`, `collectionFormat` or `example` work - I expected it to show up in the input box for each item, but it's always blank. I ended up with simply writing `value = "Sort by property value (propertyName:<asc|desc>)"`